# Screen reader not working when I add this code

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, accessibility

```js
//Getting the height of the header
        let headerHeight = document.querySelector('header');
        let height = headerHeight.offsetHeight;

        //Adjusting the #navbarNav's top margin to accommadate the header 
        let nn = document.getElementById("navbarNav");
        nn.style.top = height.toString() + "px";

let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamMenuButton");
      let shown = false;
      hamburger.addEventListener("click", function () {
          if (shown) { //if #navbarNav is showing 
              hideNN();
          } else { //if not 
              showNN();
          }
      });
      let i = document.getElementById("ham-img");
      let memberUN = document.getElementById("member-un");
      function showNN() {
          //********************This is causing the problem********************
          memberUN.style.display = "none";
          //memberUN.style.visibility = "hidden";
          //memberUN.hidden = true;

          shown = true;
      }

      function hideNN() {
          //********************This is causing the problem********************
          memberUN.style.display = "flex";
          //memberUN.style.visibility = "visible";
          //memberUN.hidden = false;
          

          shown = false;
      }
```

```css
header {
display: flex;
}

#hamMenuButton:focus {
border: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar-toggler {
outline: none!important;
box-shadow: none!important;
border: none!important;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
outline: none!important;
box-shadow: none!important;
border: 1px solid black!important;
            }

#navbarNav {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>SOF</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <section class="dropdown my-1" id="member-un">
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">
                <p>Hello, John Smith</p>
              </button>
              <!-- This is where the issue is -->
              <section class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item py-3" href="" id="drop-logout">Logout</a>
              </section>
            </section>
            
            <nav class="navbar" id="hamburger-menu">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" 
            id="hamMenuButton" 
            type="button" 
            data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav" 
            aria-expanded="false" 
            aria-controls="navbarNav">
                Menu
            </button>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
        <section class="collapse py-5" id="navbarNav">
            <p>Hello, John Smith</p>
        </section>
        
        <main>
        <!--Rest of the code-->
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm working with NVDA screen reader to test for accessibility on a site and I'm using Bootstrap. I'm trying to add an overlay menu that toggles between shown and hidden when the user hits a hamburger button. It covers the main and not the header portion of the site.

When the overlay is shown, I want to hide the member-un element. The code works fine. However, when I use the NVDA screen reader, I want the screen reader to say "Expanded" and "Collapsed" every time the hamburger button is hit.

As soon as I add the "memberUN.style.display = "none";" and "memberUN.style.display = "flex";" lines, the screen reader decides not to say "Expanded" and "Collapsed" anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're trying to manage the visibility of the bootstrap navbar component using `element.style.display`,  `element.style.visibility` and `element.hidden`. Bootstrap's JavaScript automatically opens and closes the navbar component while also managing the `aria-expanded` attribute and setting appropriate CSS classes. If you want to build on top of the existing functionality, that's fine, but I see no reason to try to replicate what's already been done.

Comment: I'm trying to hide the #member-un element which doesn't automatically become hidden when I open the overlay.

Comment: does this do what you need? https://codepen.io/joshschroder/pen/abGoJgQ

Comment: Why would you want to hide an element outside a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not common to use `aria-expanded` together with a dialog, and Bootstrap will not update it.

The reason is that an element inside the dialog is focussed as soon as the dialog opens. The status of the button therefore would not be announced anyway.

Focus is then trapped inside the dialog, so the button cannot be announced.

When the dialog closes, the button is focussed again, but then it’s already obvious that focus left the dialog.

See [the Dialog Pattern on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/)

### Don’t use a dialog to open a navigation

You are hiding an element that is outside the dialog, while it is open. This doesn’t do anything for a screen reader user, since they are trapped inside the dialog.

The same counts for other users. The whole point of a modal dialog is to force the user’s attention on it’s content. Usually a backdrop is applied as well. So I don’t see the point in hiding something in the main page while a dialog is open.

The current code refers to a nav bar and a burger. Usage of a modal dialog to display a navigation seems very weird, which is probably the reason why things don’t work as you’d expect.

To hide a navigation you might want to look at a [Menu Button](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubutton/) or [the Disclosure Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/)